# Return values from array1 that are not in array2

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
arr1 = [
  {
    empID: 1,
    empName: 'Sam'
  },
  {
    empID: 2,
    empName: 'Robert'
  },
  {
    empID: 3,
    empName: 'Josh'
  },
  {
    empID: 4,
    empName: 'Kane'
  }
];

arr2 = [2, 3]
```

I want to return only `empID` from arr1, which are not present in arr2, i.e. 1 & 4. I am not able to use `find()` and `filter()` appropriately.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `arr1.filter()`, and the filter function should use `arr2.includes()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const employees = arr1.filter(emp => !arr2.includes(emp.empID));
```